# In PIG how to remove similar values

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

in my pig script i have a column for country1 and country2 and an id.  In my country field, some of the values are similar like below.  How do I filter out similar values that have at least **2 consecutive** of the same characters?

Ex:

```
a = load file
a = generate id, country1, country2
```

output:

```
id1, us, usa
id2, gb, gba
id3, in, ind
id4, in, usa

expected output:
id4, in, usa
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to reduce 4 rows to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SUBSTRING](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#SUBSTRING)  to get the first two characters of the 3rd column and compare that with the 2nd column value.

```
B = FILTER A BY (LOWER(A.$1) != SUBSTRING(LOWER(A.$2),0,2));
DUMP B;
```